# I call method without object why is it run?

Tags: java

```
public class SalaryManager {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SalaryManager sm=new SalaryManager();
    System.out.println(sm.getMonthlySalary(20000000));
}

public double getMonthlySalary(int yearlySalary) {
    double monthlysalary=yearlySalary/12.0;
    
    double tax=calculateTax(monthlysalary);//HERE
    double pension=calculateNationalPension(monthlysalary);//HERE
    double insurance=calculateHealthInsurance(monthlysalary);//HERE
    double sum=tax+pension+insurance;
    
    monthlysalary-=sum;
    
    return monthlysalary;
}

public double calculateTax(double monthSalary) {
    return monthSalary*0.125;
    
}

public double calculateNationalPension(double monthSalary) {
    double pension=monthSalary*0.081;
    
    return pension;
}

public double calculateHealthInsurance(double monthSalary) {
    double insurance=monthSalary*0.135;
    
    return insurance;
}
}
```

I know that if I call method, then I must make object without static method;
But I call method without object in "getMonthlySalary Method", It run well.
How does this code work?

Comment: what do you call this `SalaryManager sm=new SalaryManager();`

Comment: Where do you think you called `getMonthlySalary` without an object?

Answer (score 4):

When you are already in a member method, something like `calculateTax(monthlysalary);` is shorthand for `this.calculateTax(monthlysalary);`. You are calling the method **on the current object**. To understand this better, learn about what `this` means in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can call any method from "getMonthlySalary" method as this method is not static method. You already have created an object in main method and then you called the method "getMonthlySalary". So the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely impossible to call a non-static method without an object attached to it.
A non-static method enables the programmer to access the members of an object in two especially notable ways:

1. Via the **this** keyword
2. Accessing other members of the object **directly** without
   referring to the object explicitly.

The statements you believe are functioning without an object linked to them are actually accessing the object's members in the latter manner.

So, for an object of the following form:

```
obj a
{
 var one;
 non-static method two();
}
```

Inside the non-static method two():

**a.one** is equivalent to both **this.one** and **one**.